# How to view log of why device manager keeps chiming?

Tags: windows, device-manager

The device manager chime keeps randomly going off, every few minutes or seconds.

The Device Manager window, when open, will flash and refresh when this happens, but I don't see any problems.

Does Device Manager have a log that I can open and examine?

Comment: Open the complete device manager tree (all items) and look for yellow or red marks on icons indicating need to update / install.

Comment: Open event viewer, and review the list of system events